# how I can make a vector by using 2 columns in data set

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these two columns in my data.frame :

```
df1 <- structure(list(Mode = c("car", "walk", "passenger", "car", "bus"
), Licence = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df1
#        Mode Licence
# 1       car       1
# 2      walk       1
# 3 passenger       0
# 4       car       1
# 5       bus       1
```

I want to make an indicator vector b, that is 1 if the mode of that person is not car an have a driver licence and 0 otherwise. in the above example I need d to be:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Mode = c("car", "walk", "passenger", "car", "bus"
), Licence = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1), b = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                    -5L), class = "data.frame")
df2
#        Mode Licence b
# 1       car       1 0
# 2      walk       1 1
# 3 passenger       0 0
# 4       car       1 0
# 5       bus       1 1
```

Comment: `transform(dat, b =  Licence - (Mode == "car"))` is an option.

Comment: `df1$Licence * (df1$Mode != "car")` is another.

Comment: @markus how about if I wanna make indicator if Mode is car? (without caring about the other variable). the above code will change a lot?

Comment: Do you need `dat$is_car <- dat$Mode == "car"` ?

Comment: oh yea! or I can use as.integer(df$Mode)

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you need an integer column, try `dat$is_car <- as.integer(dat$Mode == "car")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using logical operations and implicit conversion between numeric and logical:

```
df1$b <- with(df1, Mode!="car" & Licence)*1
```

Note: `0` is equivalent to `FALSE` and everything else is equivalent to `TRUE`, so if the possible values are just 0 and 1, we can shorten `Licence == 1` to just `Licence`. The `*1` part at he end converts truth values to `0`'s and `1`'s again.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. You could use "ifelse" statements for this as its easier to understand.

```
data = data.frame(mode = c("car", "walk", "passanger", "car", "bus"), License = c(1,1,0,1,1))

data$b = ifelse(data$mode !="car" & data$License == 1, 1,0)
```

Comment: A bit more concise: `as.integer(dat$Mode !="car" & dat$Licence == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(b = if_else(Mode %in% c('walk', 'bus')&Licence == 1, # condition
                           true = 1,
                           false = 0))
```